# How to use $and in pymongo without syntax problem?

Tags: pymongo

I'm confused why this isn't working

for record in mycollection.find({$and: [ {"PARTNER_SOURCE":"InLife"}, {"HOLDINGMATCHES": {"$exists": "true"}} ] }):

give this error:

File "./outputleads.py", line 15
    for record in mycollection.find({$and: [ {"PARTNER_SOURCE":"InLife"}, {"HOLDINGMATCHES": {"$exists": "true"}} ] }):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It's giving syntax error right on the $ on $and

What is wrong with it?

This works just fine as a filter right on the mongodb interface: 
{$and: [ {"PARTNER_SOURCE":"InLife"}, {"HOLDINGMATCHES": {"$exists": "true"}} ] }

Answer (score 0):

$and needs to be in quotes... everything needs to be in "" apparently.

for record in mycollection.find({"$and": [ {"PARTNER_SOURCE":"InLife"}, {"HOLDINGMATCHES": {"$exists": "true"}} ] }):